# What is the difference between this `doseq` statement and a `for` statement; reading file in clojure?

Tags: clojure

If you have been following my questions over the day,

I am doing a class project in clojure and having difficulty reading a file, parsing it, and creating a graph from its content. I have managed to open and read a file along with parsing the lines as needed. The issue I face now is creating a graph structure from the data that was read in.

Some background first. In other functions I have implemented in this project I have used a `for` statement to "build up" a list of values as such

```
...
(let [rem-list (remove nil? (for [j (range (count (graph n)))]
    (cond (< (rand) 0.5)
        [n (nth (seq (graph n)) j)])))
...
```

This `for` would build up a list of edges to remove from a graph, after it was done I could then use `rem-list` in a `reduce` to remove all of the edges from some graph structure.

Back to my issue. I figured that if I were to read a file line by line I could "build up" a list in the same manner so I implemented the function below

```
(defn readGraphFile [filename, numnodes]
  (let [edge-list 
        (with-open [rdr (io/reader filename)]
          (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
           (lineToEdge line)))]
    (edge-list)))
```

Though if I am to run this function I end up with a null pointer exception as if nothing was ever "added" to `edge-list`. So being the lazy/good? programmer I am I quickly thought of another way. Though it still somewhat relies on my thinking of how the `for` built the list.

In this function I first `let [graph` be equal to an empty graph with the known number of nodes. Then each time that a line was read I would simply add that edge (each line in the file is an edge) to the graph, in effect "building up" my graph. The function is shown below

```
(defn readGraph [filename, numnodes]
  (let [graph (empty-graph numnodes)]
    (with-open [rdr (io/reader filename)]
      (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
        (add-edge graph (lineToEdge line))))
    graph))
```

Here `lineToEdge` returns a pair of numbers (ex `[1 2]`). Which is proper input for the `add-edge` function.

```
finalproject.core> (add-edge (empty-graph 5) (lineToEdge "e 1 2"))
[#{} #{2} #{1} #{} #{}]
```

The issue with this function though is that it seems to never actually add an edge to a graph

```
finalproject.core> (readGraph "/home/eccomp/finalproject/resources/11nodes.txt" 11)
[#{} #{} #{} #{} #{} #{} #{} #{} #{} #{} #{}]
```

So I guess my issue lies with how `doseq` is different from `for`? Is it different or is my implementation incorrect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`doseq` differs from `for` in that it is intended for running a function on a sequence just for the side effects.

If you look at the documentation for `doseq`:
(https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq)

> Repeatedly executes body (presumably for side-effects) with
>   bindings and filtering as provided by "for".  Does not retain
>   the head of the sequence. Returns nil

So, regardless of any processing you're doing, `nil` will just be returned.

You can switch `doseq` with `for`, and it should work. However, `line-seq` is lazy, so what you might have to do is wrap it in a `doall` to ensure that it will try to read all the lines when the file is open.

Also, your second readGraph function will only return an empty graph:

```
(defn readGraph [filename, numnodes]
  (let [graph (empty-graph numnodes)]
    (with-open [rdr (io/reader filename)]
      (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
        (add-edge graph (lineToEdge line))))
    graph))
```

The final line is just the empty graph you set with `let`, since Clojure is an immutable language, the graph reference is never updated, since you have a function that takes an existing graph and adds an edge to it, you need to step though the list while passing the list that you're building up.

I know there must be a better way to do this, but I'm not as good at Clojure as I would like, but something like:

```
(defn readGraph
  [filename numnodes]
  (with-open [rdr (io/reader filename)]
    (let [edge-seq (line-seq rdr)]
        (loop [cur-line (first edge-seq)
               rem-line (rest edge-seq)
               graph (empty-graph numnodes)]
          (if-not cur-line
            graph
            (recur (first rem-line)
                   (rest rem-line)
                   (add-edge graph (lineToEdge cur-line))))))))
```

Might give you something closer to what you're after.

---

Thinking about it a little more, you could try using reduce, so:

```
(defn readGraph
  [filename numnodes]
  (with-open [rdr (io/reader filename)]
    (reduce add-edge (cons (empty-graph numnodes)
                           (doall (line-seq rdr))))))
```

Reduce will go through a sequence, applying the function you pass in to the first two arguments, then passing in the result of that as the first argument to the next call. The `cons` is there, so we can be sure an empty graph is the first argument that is passed in.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this makes a lot more sense to me now. We have been talking about lazy sequences lately and this fits right in there with that. I like the solution you provide and I have tried, a few times now, to get it to work for me though not matter the implementation  I get the error "IllegalArgumentException No matching field found: close for class clojure.lang.Cons" I have tried to rewrite it multiple ways and just can't get anywhere, does this error mean anything to you in the context of this problem?

Comment: I will try and see if I can figure it out later, working without a REPL handy makes it difficult. :)

Comment: Ahh, whoops. I have edge-seq in the "with-open" which is wrong. I will correct when I get home.

Comment: I have tried more to fix the issues, I have basically come down to what is outlined in the question linked at the end. It seems as soon as I try to add in the logic to alter the graph in the loop I get an error. I can understand the error but not how it arises. // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313337/what-is-the-difference-and-issues-between-these-two-clojure-functions

Comment: I've updated my answer to fix the problem you were getting, and also added another possible approach at the end.

Comment: Ok, I think that gets me closer, the only issue now is that the parsing from the string line to a pair of values parses to longs and not ints. So I think this should work. That you very much Mike!

Answer (score 0):

You could easily find an answer to your question in Clojure documentation.

You could find complete documentation for all core functions on [clojuredocs.org](https://clojuredocs.org/) website, or you could simply run `(doc <function name>)` in your Clojure REPL.

Here is what [`doseq` function documentation](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq) says:

```
=> (doc doseq)
(doc doseq)
-------------------------
clojure.core/doseq
([seq-exprs & body])
Macro
  Repeatedly executes body (presumably for side-effects) with
  bindings and filtering as provided by "for".  Does not retain
  the head of the sequence. Returns nil.
```

In other words, in always returns `nil`. So, the only way you could use it is to cause some side-effects (e.g. repeatedly print something to your console).

And here is what [`for` function documentation](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for) says:

```
=> (doc for)
(doc for)
-------------------------
clojure.core/for
([seq-exprs body-expr])
Macro
  List comprehension. Takes a vector of one or more
   binding-form/collection-expr pairs, each followed by zero or more
   modifiers, and yields a lazy sequence of evaluations of expr.
   Collections are iterated in a nested fashion, rightmost fastest,
   and nested coll-exprs can refer to bindings created in prior
   binding-forms.  Supported modifiers are: :let [binding-form expr ...],
   :while test, :when test.

  (take 100 (for [x (range 100000000) y (range 1000000) :while (< y x)] [x y]))
```

So, `for` function produces a lazy sequence which you could bind to some variable and use later in your code.

Note that produced sequence is *lazy*. It means that elements of this sequence will not be computed until you'll try to use (or print) them. For example, the following function:

```
(defn noop []
  (for [i (range 10)]
    (println i))
  nil)
```

won't print anything, since `for` loop result is not used and thus not computed. You could force evaluation of a lazy sequence using [`doall` function](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doall).